# Are there critical sections in the following code?

Tags: c, multithreading, critical-section, critical-region

The following code pieces are been called regularly by multiple threads in a single process. The question here is, are there critical sections?

First Code:

```
struct object {
    struct object *nxt;
};

void delete(object **top, object *deletable) {
    object *current, *pred;
    if (*top == deletable) {
        *top = deletable->nxt;
} else {
    pred = top;
    current = (*top)->nxt;
    while (current && (current != deletable)) {
        pred = current;
        current = current->nxt;
    }
    if (current) {
        pred = current->nxt;
    }
}
```

Second Code;

```
int shift(int param) {
    int result = 654321;
    result = result ^ param;
    param = param * result;
    result = (param >> 9) ^ ~result;
    return result;
}
```

Currently i don't think that there are any critical sections, because the variables don't manipulate the same data. But I am not sure about this. I am pretty new to critical sections and multithreading.

Comment: Is it possible that an outer caller will call these functions as well? The functions doesn't have any internal states, but when accessing the data structures a parallel call of them could cause serious trouble. So my recommendation: lock them when using them.

Comment: thanks for the answer! what exactly do you mean by outer caller? its been given, that multiple threads in a single process are running the code pieces, but no other processes or threads in other processes are running the code pieces.

Comment: @Dos to answer the question you asked: No there are not, there are no synchronization primitives at all in any of that code. However that's not necessarily a bad thing if the data being operated on is only ever touched from one thread at a time and you can prove this.

Comment: The first one is a linked list implementation - If you can guarantee that each thread operates on its own list (and list elements), you're safe. If not, you'll definitely get into trouble. The second one should generally be safe.

Comment: @Dos Realize first that thread-safety is not so much about *code* being shared between threads - It's about *data* that may be manipulated concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no global and/or static variables in your code.

There are no other types of shared resources (e.g., the same file used in different places).

Therefore, there are no critical sections here.